# Add single file into a TAR

Tags: linux, tar

I have a tar archive named `backup.tar`. I want to add a file named `sshd.conf` into this `tar` archive.

Comment: Feedback: I downvoted because the question shows no research effort at all.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Sometimes I wonder about people who post question and don't try just `man tar` or googling "Add single file into a TAR". I wonder what to do if I googling phrase in the topic? First result is the answer to the question ([how-to-add-files-to-archive](http://www.lostsaloon.com/technology/how-to-add-files-to-archive-file-in-linux-also-delete-files/). So how much time I will spend when I post a question? Of cause it's much more then googling question. -1

Answer (score 5):

From `man tar`:

```
-r, --append
              Append files to the end of an archive.  Arguments have the same meaning as for -c (--create).
```

So, in your case,

`tar -rf backup.tar sshd.conf`

should do the trick